# Django CircularDependencyError on migrations

Tags: python, django, pycharm

I cloned a git repository with a Django app and opened it on Pycharm and made some changes to it.

Among these changes I did `add_to_class` on the Group class from django, to add a field named `modulo`.

I closed this project and cloned the repository again, and made all the initial migrations and all. The problem is, when I try to `migrate` I get this error

```
django.db.migrations.exceptions.CircularDependencyError: BOXCFG.0001_initial, auth.0010_remove_group_modulo, auth.0009_group_modulo
```

Seems like the changes I did on the Django native model are still somehow getting in the way of my migrations.

I tried deleting everything, migration history, the table migration field, the folders the database... And I still get this error when trying to make my migrations.

How do I solve this? Where can I clear the Django migrations so that I start all over again without the changes I did in another project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just solved the problem. For anyone facing the same issue what I did was delete the migrations that were causing the error in the `django\contrib\auth\migrations` folder.

Also deleted them from the pycache.

After that I deleted the database did the `makemigrations` on my app again and then did the `migrate`. Seems like it worked.